# .htaccess redirect in joomla has wrong css

Tags: css, .htaccess, redirect, joomla2.5

The overall goal is to create a twitter-like site where if you try to go to any of the pages that are not indicated, you will be taken to a profile page instead. While this is somewhat simple in most cases it becomes a bit more complicated inside of Joomla due to the fact that the !-f command is a bit useless. Article titles don't actually exist so this one does not.

The only alternative that I have functioning is to list every page I don't want to redirect as a condition. The result is something like this. The Custom redirects is the section in question.

```
# Use PHP5.3 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php

RewriteEngine on


#Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

## Mod_rewrite in use.

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !how-it-works
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !plans-and-pricing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !contact-us
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !login
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?option=com_profiles&view=publica&Name=$1 [R=301]
## End - Custom redirects 

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Now this works perfectly with one minor hitch. It appears that the css for this page is actually using the referring page's. Joomla is made modularly so the template calls for a content section and the content section is being replaced while the rest is not. This includes header files linking to style sheets.

I was hoping some of the people here might be able to take a look at this and tell me what is preventing this from being a proper redirect. I don't really use htacess so some of the nuances are lost on me.